# Kendo Grid's Inline Kendo Dropdown values not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm just trying to create a kendo grid with an inline kendo dropdown. like the following

[example 1](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom?_ga=2.25987325.1184282148.1612853896-1345383271.1612853896)

[example 2](https://www.sitereq.com/post/kendo-mvc-dropdown-lists-inside-inline-kendo-mvc-grids)

[image]

I keep Database Values like following

[image]

So, the **SampleModel**, I created like this, I just keep only **TypeId** in DB

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }


    public int TypeId { get; set; }     

    public string TypeName{ get; set; }

}

public class ListItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

this is the grid code snippet that includes, EditorTemplate name

```
                @(Html
                    .Kendo()
                    .Grid<SampleModel>()
                    .Name("grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);               
                        columns.Bound(e => e.TypeId).EditorTemplateName("Type").Title("Type").ClientTemplate("#:TypeName#");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Description);

                        columns.Command(p =>
                        {
                            
                            p.Edit();
                            p.Destroy();
                        });

                    })
                    .ToolBar(t =>
                    {
                        t.Create();
                    })
                    
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(m =>
                        {
                            m.Id(mr => mr.Id);
                            
                        })                                
                        .Create(cr => cr.Action("Create", "Sample"))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Sample"))
                        .Update(upd => upd.Action("Update", "Sample"))
                        .Destroy(dest => dest.Action("Delete", "Sample"))
                    )
        )
```

So this is my Editor template code snippet

```
@using System.Collections
@model System.Int32
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Types).DataValueField("Id").DataTextField("Name").Name("TypeId"))
```

so I implement the code like following

```
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
       
        ViewBag.Types = GetTypes();        
        var res = sampleService.GetDB_Data();          

        return Json(res.Data.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }  

    public List<ListItem> GetTypes() 
    {
        List<ListItem> types = new List<ListItem>();

        types.Add(new ListItem()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Good"
        }
        );
        types.Add(new ListItem() 
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Bad"
        }
        );
        return types;
    }
```

but this is not mapping or not loading the dropdowns as seen on these images

Not Mapping values as seen in this image,

[image]

Not even load kendo dropdown, in the backend I can see **GetTypes()** return values, but when it comes to frontend it's showing like this

[image]

Appreciate if can show the mistake or modification required for this

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to the name of the editor. Instead of explicitly specifying a name, use the DropDownFor helper and let the widget generate the name for you.

e.g.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x=> x).BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Types).DataValueField("Id").DataTextField("Name"))
```

Comment: nope, this doesn't works `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: expression` getting this error after removing the name

Comment: Please note that I use the DropDownListFor helper which accepts a predicate as a parameter, not DropDownList with no parameters. The DropDownListFor should not require a name as it generates it from the model.